# Laptop mouse excessively sensitive and makes random movements and clicks

Tags: mouse-cursor

I have a laptop and the mouse on it is very sensitive.  I have tried to adjust the settings and taken the laptop to professional technicians to slow it down but nothing works.  I can be working in any application and the mouse will minimized the page and go to another open application.  It will automatically select text, while typing and delete it.  Its like the darn thing is possessed.  Is there anything I can do?

Comment: *"the mouse will [minimise] the page and go to another open application. It will automatically select text, while typing and delete it"* Um, that goes way beyond the far end of the 'sensitivity'/DPI scale...

Comment: The title should be descriptive of the issue at hand. A date should not be embedded in the title because the date and time are recorded with every post. You should consider editing your question to improve the title.

Comment: What sort of laptop and touchpad?  Or is it an external mouse?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Mouse 08082015, but in general, here's my approach to fixing hypersensitive mice:

- make sure have the right driver (sometimes need to contact manufacturer)
- edit settings to adjust the palm check and sensitivity levels -- note, humidity can make things work strangely

How do things go when you work with an external mouse?

Comment: 08082015 might be a date